# Derive an optimized case-of expression from a function that takes a closed set as its input

Tags: haskell

I have a closed set of values:

```
data Value = A | B | C | D | E ...
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

And a data structure that represents their order:

```
order :: [[Value]]
order = [
  [ B ],
  [ A, D ],
  [ C ],
  ...
  ]
```

I need to convert a Value's order into an `Int`. I could do it like this:

```
prec' :: [[Value]] -> Value -> Int
prec' [] _ = 0
prec' (vs : rest) v = if v `elem` vs
  then 1 + length rest
  else prec' rest v

prec :: Value -> Int
prec = prec' order
```

However this `prec` has complexity O(n).

What I would want, is a very lightweight and optimized function like this one:

```
prec :: Value -> Int
prec = \case
  A -> 2
  B -> 3
  C -> 1
  D -> 2
  E -> 0
  ...
```

But of course I don't want to write it manually, otherwise it risks being inconsistent with the information stored in `order`. The Haskell compiler should be able to derive that function on its own easily, since its input is a closed set.

How can I get GHC to generate a function like the latest definition of `prec`?

Comment: Perhaps use some ad hoc [Data.Map](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.4.0.0/docs/Data-Map.html) object ?

Comment: @jpmarinier: Data.Map would reduce the complexity, but still far away from optimal. To be honest, this is not a bottle neck or anything. I'm trying to optimize this thing mainly in order to learn.

Comment: Perhaps define `prec`, then use it to *generate* `order`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite your `prec'` function using a *fold*, in this case `foldl'`, and add `INLINE` pragmas to `prec'` and `order`.

```hs
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Maybe

data Value = A | B | C | D | E
  deriving (Eq)

prec' :: Value -> [[Value]] -> Int
prec' v = fromMaybe 0 . foldl' f Nothing
  where
    f (Just !len) _ = Just (len + 1)
    f Nothing vs | v `elem` vs = Just 1
                 | otherwise = Nothing
{-# INLINE prec' #-}

order :: [[Value]]
order = [
  [ B ],
  [ A, D ],
  [ C ]
  ]
{-# INLINE order #-}
  
prec :: Value -> Int
prec v = prec' v order
```

Compiling [this](https://play.haskell.org/saved/8E7KgwEU) with GHC 9.6 I get the following simplifier output (using `-ddump-simpl` and some `-dsuppress-*` options):

```hs
prec1 :: Int
prec1 = I# 0#

prec2 :: Int
prec2 = I# 1#

-- snip --

lvl1 :: Int
lvl1 = I# 2#

lvl2 :: Int
lvl2 = I# 3#

prec :: Value -> Int
prec
  = \ (v :: Value) ->
      case v of {
        __DEFAULT -> lvl1;
        B -> lvl2;
        C -> prec2;
        E -> prec1
      }
```

### Why does this work?

When you write a list literal, GHC will actually desugar it using the [`build`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/GHC-Exts.html#v:build) function, which means that if you use a fold then your function can potentially participate in list fusion. For example, if I compile your `order` with `-ddump-ds` (which dumps the desugaring output as GHC Core) then I get the following result:

```hs
order
  = build
      (\ (@a_d1Pf)
         (c_d1Pg :: [Value] -> a_d1Pf -> a_d1Pf)
         (n_d1Ph :: a_d1Pf) ->
         c_d1Pg
           (build
              (\ (@a_d1P4)
                 (c_d1P5 :: Value -> a_d1P4 -> a_d1P4)
                 (n_d1P6 :: a_d1P4) ->
                 c_d1P5 B n_d1P6))
           (c_d1Pg
              (build
                 (\ (@a_d1P9)
                    (c_d1Pa :: Value -> a_d1P9 -> a_d1P9)
                    (n_d1Pb :: a_d1P9) ->
                    c_d1Pa A (c_d1Pa D n_d1Pb)))
              (c_d1Pg
                 (build
                    (\ (@a_d1Pc)
                       (c_d1Pd :: Value -> a_d1Pc -> a_d1Pc)
                       (n_d1Pe :: a_d1Pc) ->
                       c_d1Pd C n_d1Pe))
                 n_d1Ph)))
```

So with enough inlining and the fact that both `elem` and `foldl'` participate in list fusion as good consumers, the simplifier can optimize your function aggressively using rewrite rules.

Answer (score 8):

Solution 1: Use Template Haskell to generate the code you want.

Solution 2 (expanded below): (Ab)use the simplifier.

The main obstacle to simplification is that GHC will not inline recursive functions. One workaround is to do the recursion through type classes.

```
-- Intuitively unroll :: Nat -> (a -> a) -> (a -> a)
-- but the nat is now a type-level parameter.
class Unroll (n :: Nat) where
  unroll :: (a -> a) -> (a -> a)

instance Unroll 0 where
  unroll = id

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} Unroll (n-1) => Unroll n where
  unroll f = f . unroll @(n-1) f
```

This lets you define the following fixpoint operator that unfolds the first n iterations:

```
unrollfix :: forall n a. Unroll n => (a -> a) -> a
unrollfix f = unroll @n f (fix f)
```

You then need to write all recursive functions using `fix`, and replace `fix` with `unrollfix`. You have to sprinkle some `INLINE` pragmas around too.

`elem` with `fix`:

```
elem :: forall a. Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
elem = fix go
  where
    go elem_ x [] = False
    go elem_ x (y : ys) = x == y || elem_ x ys
```

`elem` with `unrollfix`:

```
{-# INLINE uelem #-}
uelem :: forall n a. (Unroll n, Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
uelem = unrollfix @n go
  where
    go elem_ x [] = False
    go elem_ x (y : ys) = x == y || elem_ x ys
```

Also `length` (omitted), and `prec'`.

`prec'` with `fix`:

```
prec' :: forall a. Eq a => [[a]] -> a -> Int
prec' = fix go
  where
    go prec_ [] v = 0
    go prec_ (vs : rest) v = if elem v vs
      then 1 + length rest
      else prec_ rest v
```

`prec'` with `unrollfix`:

```
prec' :: forall n a. (Unroll n, Eq a) => [[a]] -> a -> Int
prec' = unrollfix @n go
  where
    go prec_ [] v = 0
    go prec_ (vs : rest) v = if uelem @n v vs
      then 1 + ulength @n rest
      else prec_ rest v
    {-# INLINE go #-}
```

Finally, set the `n` parameter to a high enough value to enable simplification.

```
prec :: Value -> Int
prec v = prec' @5 order v
```

---

Full code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes, DataKinds, MultiParamTypeClasses, ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications, UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -ddump-simpl #-}
module A (Value(..), prec) where

import GHC.TypeNats
import Data.Function (fix)
import GHC.Exts

class Unroll (n :: Nat) where
  unroll :: (a -> a) -> (a -> a)

instance Unroll 0 where
  unroll = id

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} Unroll (n-1) => Unroll n where
  unroll f = f . unroll @(n-1) f

unrollfix :: forall n a. Unroll n => (a -> a) -> a
unrollfix f = unroll @n f (fix f)

data Value = A | B | C | D | E
  deriving Eq

order :: [[Value]]
order = [[A], [B, C], [D], [E]] 

{-# INLINE uelem #-}
uelem :: forall n a. (Unroll n, Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
uelem = unrollfix @n go
  where
    go elem_ x [] = False
    go elem_ x (y : ys) = x == y || elem_ x ys
    {-# INLINE go #-}

{-# INLINE ulength #-}
ulength :: forall n a. Unroll n => [a] -> Int
ulength = unrollfix @n go
  where
    go length_ [] = 0
    go length_ (_ : xs) = 1 + length_ xs
    {-# INLINE go #-}

prec' :: forall n a. (Unroll n, Eq a) => [[a]] -> a -> Int
prec' = unrollfix @n go
  where
    {-# INLINE go #-}
    go prec_ [] v = 0
    go prec_ (vs : rest) v = if uelem @n v vs
      then 1 + ulength @n rest
      else prec_ rest v

prec :: Value -> Int
prec v = prec' @5 order v
```

Generated Core (using the `-ddump-simpl` option) (look at the unfolding, instead of the main definition):

```
\ (v_aQC [Occ=Once1!] :: Value) ->
                 case v_aQC of {
                   __DEFAULT -> GHC.Types.I# 3#;
                   A -> GHC.Types.I# 4#;
                   D -> GHC.Types.I# 2#;
                   E -> GHC.Types.I# 1#
                 }
```

Comment: Wow! This answer is beautiful, but it's fraightening too. I'll look around for an unrolling library that provides all the functions and typeclasses I need... Otherwise I think I may opt for some less elegant solutions. Regardless, I'm impressed.

Comment: It's not important, and it might actually be better style to put it in front. I'll fix it.

Comment: I tried to play around with this solution, but in practice it feels a bit too brittle... The main issue is that if I pick the wrong `n :: Nat` (e.g. add an extra `prec` layer but forget to increase `n`), the generated code will be sub-optimal and I won't have any way to know unless I look at the generated code. I'm afraid that the only real solution involves using Template Haskell.

Comment: That's fair. I think it can be improved a little by using length-indexed lists, so the typing information tells you how much to unroll but it's quite the extra complexity.

Answer (score 4):

I would just wrap a general-purpose memoization tool around the function, like [`MemoTrie`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MemoTrie) or [`memoize`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/memoize) or [`fastmemo`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fastmemo-0.1.1/docs/Data-Function-FastMemo.html).

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, DeriveAnyClass #-}

import Data.Function.FastMemo

data Value = A | B | C | D | E ...
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Generic, Memoizable)

prec :: Value -> Int
prec = memoize $ prec' order
```

This may not be as optimized as a direct TH solution, but the `Generic`-derived `Memoizable` instance should result something reasonably similar. Not sure which of these packages do it best.

Comment: I'm a bit annoyed that the various memoization libraries would result in some code which is both slower and would take more space. The solution I was dreaming for shouldn't be hard to achieve for GHC... However, it seems like GHC can't do that easily. So I'm probably going to use one of the libraries you suggest, to keep the code light. I hope you don't mind that I accept Li-yao Xia's answer in spite of this. +1 and thanks for suggesting those packages.

Answer (score 4):

Define `prec` first, then generate `order` using `prec`.

```
prec :: Value -> Int
prec = \case
  A -> 2
  B -> 3
  C -> 1
  D -> 2
  E -> 0


order :: [[Value]]
order = go [A, B, C, D, E]
  where eqPrec = (==) `on` prec
        ordPrec = compare `on` prec
        go = reverse . groupBy eqPrec . sortBy ordPrec
```

Comment: Yeah... This solution is probably the most realistic one. Unfortunately is a pain to maintain: in order to give a new data constructor `F` a prec lower than `C` and higher than `E`, you need to manually increment the prec of all the data constructor with higher prec...

Comment: @BlueNebula you could make it `prec :: Value -> Double`, then you can always just squeeze in the new constructor between the existing ones. Bit of a hack, but should work fine.

Comment: How often do you plan on adding constructors to `Value`? I thought we were just going for a simple way to define what's already there.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: no. I need the result of `prec` for the `showsPrec` method of `Show` (among other things), which requires an `Int`.

Comment: @chepner: I believe I'll be adding new constructors somewhat often, until the project is mature. Each constructor of what I called `Value` is an operator in a programming language I'm defining. Right now I only have a few operators (few arithmetic ones), but want to add many more: probably around ~50, grouped in around ~20 levels of `prec`: that's how many e.g. JavaScript has: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table

Comment: I guess I shouldn't care about performance for something like this. This is extremely unlikely to ever be a bottleneck. However I'm curious about this problem in general... Was hoping there would be a simple solution, but it looks like that's not the case.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps one simple solution would be to do by hand what you want the compiler to do automatically once it has the `case` statement you describe -- compute a jump table.

```
import Data.Array

-- deriving Enum makes a compiler-written case statement like what you want
data Foo = A | B | C | D | E deriving (Bounded, Enum)

orderArray :: Array Int Int
orderArray = listArray
    (0, fromEnum (maxBound :: Foo) - 1)
    (orderSlow <$> [minBound..maxBound])

prec :: Foo -> Int
prec = unsafeAt orderArray . fromEnum
```

This will have to run `orderSlow` once for each possible value, but second accesses will be fast O(1) lookups.

Comment: Hm, is there a library that wraps `fromEnum` around `Array` (or `Vector`) to encapsulate the `unsafeAt`? (Of course it would still not be exactly safe, seeing how wobbly the `Enum` class is.)

Comment: This solution seems similar to the ones involving memoization structures, but it's much more compact and efficient. It's not perfect yet (data is computed at runtime and stored on the heap; the compiler won't be able to optimize using this function's result), but it's probably the best compromise. +1

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here is a TH solution ([`template-haskell-2.19.0`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.19.0.0/)):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module PrecTH where

import Language.Haskell.TH

import Data.List (nub)

prec' :: Ord a => [[a]] -> a -> Int
prec' [] _ = 0
prec' (vs : rest) v = if v `elem` vs
  then 1 + length rest
  else prec' rest v

mkPrecValueDataType :: String -> [[String]] -> DecsQ
mkPrecValueDataType dtName order = pure [
     DataD [] dtName' [] Nothing
       [ NormalC (mkName c) []
       | c <- cstrs ]
       [DerivClause Nothing $ ConT <$> [''Eq, ''Ord, ''Show ]]
   , SigD (mkName "prec")
      $ ArrowT `AppT` ConT dtName' `AppT` ConT ''Int
   , FunD (mkName "prec")
       [ Clause [ConP (mkName c) [] []]
                (NormalB . LitE . IntegerL $ slowPrec c)
                []
       | c <- cstrs ]
   ]
 where slowPrec = fromIntegral . prec' order
       cstrs = concat order -- apply `sort` here if you like the constructors in alphabetical order
       dtName' = mkName dtName
```

To be used thus

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module PrecValues where

import PrecTH

mkPrecValueDataType "Value" [["B"], ["A","D"], ["C"]]
```

and producing

```
ghci> :browse
prec :: Value -> Int
type Value :: *
data Value = B | A | D | C
ghci> prec<$>[A,B,C,D]
[2,3,1,2]
```